# dimensions on mobile browser - how is it calculated

Tags: javascript, iphone, mobile, browser

Using a Iphone 4s  with retina display - the phone dimensions are 640 x 960.

why is it that when I get the screen.width and screen.height in javascript in any browser then the dimensions returned are  320 x 480.

The samsung s4 also return inaccurate values to.

1. what is the browser/javascript doing to calculate this.
2. how does this whole process work technically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The size of the screen in pixels is 320x480 no matter the model. From: http://www.idev101.com/code/User_Interface/sizes.html  The 4s displays twice as many pixels into the space which is where the difference comes in.

**Points vs. Pixels**

> Apple introduced retina displays starting with the iPhone 4. These
>   have twice as many screen pixels as previous iPhones. You don't have
>   to modify your code to support high-res displays; the iOS coordinate
>   system uses points rather than pixels, so the dimensions and position
>   in points of all UI elements remains the same across all devices.

Comment: There's a good write-up of developing for android devices with different screen sizes and densities @ https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities.html